# How to solve "The class with java.io.File and name of java.io.File is not trusted." Spring batch test error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jackson, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application and I am writing test cases for it. The application runs without any error. I could also unit tests the `Steps` in the application without any problem. However when I try to lauch the `Job` and test the `Job` end to end, I face a problem as given below -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with java.io.File and name of java.io.File is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer$TrustedTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:353) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:611) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:437) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:482) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:2.13.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:133) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:104) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:324) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 86 more
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=> but was:<exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=xxFlow at state=xxFlow.step3 with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:178)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.FlowState.handle(FlowState.java:56)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:139)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:327)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastStepExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:240)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: The class with java.io.File and name of java.io.File is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["tempFile"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ContainerDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(ContainerDeserializerBase.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:621)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:437)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3674)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:324)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with java.io.File and name of java.io.File is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer$TrustedTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:611)
    ... 140 more
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
    at JobTest.inlandFlowTest(JobTest.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
```

The test for testing the job looks as follow -

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobRepositoryTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.Flow;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig({xxxConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource( locations = "/application-localtest.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("xx.xx.xx.xxx.xx")
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
public class JobTest {


    @MockBean
    SpringEmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    static {
        System.setProperty("abcd", "1");
        System.setProperty("efgh", "xx.x.xx");
    }

    @Test
    public void FlowTest()throws Exception{

        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();


        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.FAILED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());


    }
}
```

I have tried a few of the solutions present in the stackoverflow but nothing worked out. I am confused how to resolve this error and how to proceed ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are adding a `java.io.File` attribute in the execution context, which is by default not safe to serialize/deserialize. Adding the path to the file in the execution context is probably a better option (ie serialize a pointer to the file as a string rather than the file itself as a `java.io.File`).

You need to add `java.io.File` to the list of trusted classes in the `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer`. You can do that by passing the fully qualified name of the class to the [constructor of the serializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String...)) and register the customized serializer in the job repository and job explorer.